# QMediaResource::dataSize() returns zero byte size for online video

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to use [QMediaResource::dataSize()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaresource.html#dataSize) to get an online video byte size. However, it just returns zero - which is hard to believe in this case:

> This may be zero if the size is unknown.

especially for the first url.

I just want to know: (1) if it is a bug with PyQt5 or Qt5, (2) does the equivalent code in Qt5 return a nonzero result, and (3) is there any way to get the video byte size of the m3u8 url referred to?

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import *
>>> QMediaResource(QUrl('http://downdb.51voa.com/201610/will-philippines-cut-ties-with-us-and-grow-closer-to-china.mp3')).dataSize()
0
>>> QMediaResource(QUrl('https://www.the5fire.com/static/demos/diaosi.m3u8'),"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl").dataSize()
0
>>>
```

---

```
>>> QMediaResource(QNetworkRequest(QUrl('https://www.the5fire.com/static/demos/diaosi.m3u8')),"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl").dataSize()
0
>>> QMediaResource(QNetworkRequest(QUrl('https://www.the5fire.com/static/demos/diaosi.m3u8'))).dataSize()
0
>>> QMediaResource(QNetworkRequest(QUrl('http://downdb.51voa.com/201610/will-philippines-cut-ties-with-us-and-grow-closer-to-china.mp3'))).dataSize()
0
>>>
```

Comment: The size cannot be known until the resource is fully acquired. Please show **all** of your code, as otherwise it's impossible to know whether you use the `QMediaResource` class correctly.

Comment: @KubaOber (1) but the doc of QMediaResource says " The properties provide a means to assess a resource without first attempting to load it" (2) This is actually the all PyQt5 code, there are indeed some differences from the equivalent Qt5 code .

Comment: After trying this in both Python and C++ without any luck, I've searched for the `QMediaResource` [source-code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/src/multimedia/playback/qmediaresource.cpp?h=5.8), only to discover that this class is only used to store information, so no "discovery" functionality ... you need to find another way.

Comment: @Ceppo93 thanks so much!